# (Python) argparse-like processing on a string input

Tags: python

I have the need to accept a large string through a message broker (I am using RabbitMQ) and parse the string to figure out the details of the request. It would be very useful if I can do argparse-like processing on that string. Is there a way to do it or are there more elegant approaches to achieve this? My requirement is to do some detailed parsing of a string that looks like:

```
<module> <command> <command-specific-info>
```

- module is a key-word from a pre-defined list of possible values.
- command is a key-word from a pre-defined list of possible values for the chosen module
- command-specific-info is a free-form text-input expressed as a sequence of comma-separated key=value pairs

Example:

```
news headlines keyword=trump, date=mm-dd-yyyy
```

Comment: Yes, you can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

Comment: You can pass a string to `parser.parse_args` in `argparse` instead of using the cmd line. Alternatively look at the `shlex` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
In[2]: from argparse import ArgumentParser
  ...: 
  ...: parser = ArgumentParser()
  ...: parser.add_argument('module')
  ...: parser.add_argument('command')
  ...: parser.add_argument('--keyword')
  ...: parser.add_argument('--date')
  ...: 
  ...: example = 'news headlines keyword=trump, date=mm-dd-yyyy'
  ...: clean = []
  ...: for arg in example.split():
  ...:     if '=' in arg:
  ...:         clean.append('--{}'.format(arg.rstrip(',')))
  ...:     else:
  ...:         clean.append(arg)
  ...: 
  ...: args = parser.parse_args(clean)
In[3]: vars(args)
Out[3]: 
{'command': 'headlines',
 'date': 'mm-dd-yyyy',
 'keyword': 'trump',
 'module': 'news'}
```

Comment: Delirious Lettuce, brilliant! Thanks a lot. Works exactly as I wanted. Will spend more time on ArgumentParser. Quick questions:

1. Is it possible to automatically generate a help string?
2. Is it possible to define a hierarchical structure for the parser instead of a flat-list of parameters?

Comment: Hi Delirious Lettuce. Pls do send me the links that you were talking about - specifically, on nested structure as well as help-string generation. Thanks

Comment: @DiscoveringJoyOfCodingAgain Sorry for the delay, I was just referring to the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#usage and https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands  You can just use `-h` and it will print the automated help message (or you can customize it) and I think sub-commands are what you meant by nested structure. Although `argparse` can accomplish these things quite well, you might want to look into [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) as another option (if third-party is ok)

Comment: Thanks DeliriousLettuce. The sub-commands section answers all my questions except one (prefer that to click because I am not that comfortable with decorators-based usage yet). I have not yet figured out (from the documentation) how to capture the help string in a string (that I can send in a message) instead of getting it printed

Comment: @DiscoveringJoyOfCodingAgain Maybe this could help? [`ArgumentParser.format_help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.format_help)